# Erro ao tentar select com PHPOO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Bem, sou iniciante em PHPOO e desenvolvi uma classe com funções para se conectar ao banco de dados (já obtive êxito) e outra para fazer um select (onde ocorre o erro). Vou postar o código e em seguida relato o erro.

**index.php:**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require_once("class/Banco.class.php");

    $banco = new Banco("localhost", "phpoo", "root", "");

    $banco->Select();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login com PHPOO</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">

            <input type="submit" value="Logar!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Banco.class.php:**

```
<?php
class Banco {
    protected $host;
    protected $bd;
    protected $usuario;
    protected $senha;

    public function __construct($host, $bd, $usuario, $senha) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->bd = $bd;
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->senha = $senha;

        try {
            $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->bd."", $this->usuario, $this->senha,
                array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
                )
            );
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocorreu um erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function Select() {
        $listarUsuarios = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id DESC");
        $listarUsuarios->execute();

        $linhaUsuario = $listarUsuarios->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $contaUsuario = $listarUsuarios->rowCount();

        if($contaUsuario) {
            echo "Tem usuario: ".$contaUsuario;
        } else {
            echo "Nao tem usuario: ".$contaUsuario;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Ao tentar fazer o login, o seguinte erro é exibido:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPOO\class\Banco.class.php on line 29

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPOO\class\Banco.class.php on line 29
```

Como já citei anteriormente, sou iniciante em PHPOO, então, como posso resolver ambos os erros? E a maneira como estou fazendo a conexão está correta e segura?

**Obrigado!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está dizendo: Sua variável $conexao não existe. Você instanciou ela no construtor, mas no método select ela não existe. Você pode fazer o seguinte:

Na declaração da classe:

```
protected $conexao;
```

No construtor:

```
$this->conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->bd."", $this->usuario, $this->senha,
            array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
            )
        );
```

No método Select:

```
$listarUsuarios = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Quanto a maneira e a segurança de conectar, da pra dizer que está correta e relativamente segura. Outros podem contribuir mais quanto a isso.

Espero ter auxiliado.

[]s

Comment: Olá, primeiramente obrigado por responder. Então, fiz exatamente as modificações que sugeriu e os mesmos erros continuam. Em relação ao método Select está correto o $this->listarUsuarios, sendo que listarUsuarios não está sendo registrada na declaração da classe e é apenas uma simples variável?

Comment: Desculpe @Igor, falha minha. Não havia testado o código e havia colocado o $this na variável errada. Veja agora corrigido, é `$listarUsuarios = $this->conexao`

Comment: Entendendo o básico de OO: quando você acessa por ->$var está lendo um atributo da classe, que está instanciado dentro de todos os métodos, já o acesso de variáveis por $var, ou você precisa setá-lo dentro do método ou injetar como parâmetro da function, ex.: `public function($var) {}`

Comment: Obrigado, agora funcionou! Eu já havia feito essa modificação porém não havia funcionado não sei pq. Muito obrigado mesmo!